# why polyhedron was defined by linear equalities and inequalities?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am learning [convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), and confused by the definition of *polyhedron*.

it's easy understanding the *polyhedron* is defined as the solution of a finite number of linear inequalities.
But why there is also linear equalities in the definition of [convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), section 2.2.4,page 31:

> polyhedron is defined as the solution set of  a finite number of linear equalities and inequalities:
> $$
> p=\{  x| a_j^T \leq b_j, j=1, ..., m, c_j^T x = d_j, j=1, ..., p\}
> $$

linear equalities define hyperplane, not polyhedron.

As my understing: linear equalities define hyperplane, inequalities define halfspaces, intersection of finite halfspaces (it's finite linear inequalities) define polyhedron. But why there is a **linear equalities** constraint in the definition of the [convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) book. it seems unreasonable.

As illustrated in the book after definition, *Affine sets (e.g., subspaces, hyperplanes, lines), rays, line segments, and halfspaces are all polyhedra*. So, the equalities and inequalities can't be true same time?

anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear equations are allowed for convenience; we could define polyhedra using inequalities alone. For example, $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x \ge 0, y \ge 0, x+y = 1\}$$ is how we'd usually define the line segment with endpoints at $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ - which we do consider a polyhedron. But we could define the same set as $$\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x \ge 0, y \ge 0, x+y \ge 1, x+y \le 1\}$$ which doesn't have any equations in it.

We do sometimes want to say that something is a *polyhedron with nonempty interior*: that's a polyhedron $P$ with a point $\mathbf x \in P$ such that for some $r>0$, the ball of radius $r$ around $\mathbf x$ is entirely contained in $P$.

If a polyhedron has nonempty interior, it can't possibly have any linear equations in its definition. But as the example above shows, the reverse is not true: a polyhedron defined using inequalities only might still have empty interior.

Answer (score 0):

Take a  you look at the [dual linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program) of a linear program, how it behaves w.r. to inequalities or equalities in the original problem. Yes, we could write an equivalent linear problem with only inequalities, but why not be expedient.